# Open a window and close a window in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to load a new class with a UI window from a welcome screen, and at the same time close the welcome screen. When I click the button to go to open the new window it opens fine, but I would just like to close the first window on the action event.

I have tried `.hide()`, `.terminate()`, `.destroy()`, and the window still stays.

This is the relevant code:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                
        #self.email_blast_widget = EmailBlast()
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.email_blast_widget)
        self.welcome = OpeningWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.welcome)        
        bar = self.menuBar()
        file_file = bar.addMenu('File')         
        file_edit = bar.addMenu('Edit')

    def load_email(self):
        self.mail = EmailBlast()        
        self.mail.show()
        self.welcome = OpeningWindow()
        self.destroy()

class OpeningWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome To Zach's \nEmail Blast Widget")
        self.email_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Email")
        self.csv_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("CSVs")
        self.exit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Exit")

        self.init_ui()

 def init_ui(self):
    # set layout to place widgets
    self.email_button.clicked.connect(self.load_email)
    self.csv_button.clicked.connect(self.load_csv)
    #self.exit_button.clicked.connect(self.exit)
    self.exit_button.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)


class EmailBlast(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()     
        # create widgets
```

Comment: Change `self.destroy()` to `self.close()`

Comment: I have tried your code and it works as you wish, When the second sale is opened the first one is closed.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, I edited because I discovered the problem. Also, to make it exit I can answer my own question. The function is self.exit_button.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)

Comment: One thing is to close the window and another is to exit the application.

Comment: @eyllanesc right. that wouldn't be a good solution if it wasn't just the welcome screen.

Comment: You are closing your complete application, which you do not describe in your question. Take time and seriousness when you ask questions just as we do.

Answer (score 5):

```
self.exit_button.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
```

This solution works for my purposes, however, if you are trying to close a window without shutting down the application this will not work. Use self.close()

Comment: One thing is to close the window and another is to exit the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.close()` in every class you want.